# Dynamically add_action() based upon number of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wp_cron which I run every hour.

The cron calls a function which iterates through a custom post type. The title and some meta data is then used to scrape results from a remote server.

The problem is that the scraping takes a long because of the number of posts. I want to split the scraping into chunks by only iterating through 25 posts at a time. This is easy using the offset parameter in query_posts, but how do I dynamically add_action() and pass the offset variable?

In **functions.php**

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_task_hook' ) ) {
         wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_task_hook' );
}

add_action( 'my_task_hook', 'rock_n_roll' );
```

My scraper.php looks something like this

```
function rock_n_roll($offset) {

    query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'wine',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'offset' => $offset 
    )); 

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    //compare values against scraped results
    //write results to DB with update_post_meta

    endwhile;

}
```

Basically I need a way to dynamically add_action(), incrementing the value of $offset by 25 each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a variable to your [add_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action):

```
add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $arg );
```

But you can also use [do_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) instead of adding action every time your cron runs:

```
do_action( $tag, $arg )
```

Anyway, is good to store your `$offset` somewhere, so I see two options:

Store your persistent values in [WP_Object_Cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache). Maybe reading this documentation, you can find another elegant solution for your performance with large query results.

Recording in the database your actual `$offset` value using [add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) and [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

If you store `your $offset` variable, your rock_and_roll function don't need to receive a parameter anymore, you just need to retrieve it inside the function.

```
function rock_n_roll() {

    // Retrieve $offset value from WP_Object_Cache
    // or from database with get_option()

    query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'wine',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'offset' => $offset 
    )); 

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    //compare values against scraped results
    //write results to DB with update_post_meta

    endwhile;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $Offset is passed to the function from another source.. So I could imagine, something like:

```
$Var = $Pre_definedoffset;
$Var = $Pre_definedoffset + 25; 
rock_n_roll($var);
```

This is just assumptions from what I can see from your code.

You will need to modify the variable containing the integer which is passed through to your function, before the code pushes it through the function.